# laravel elixir script not building when compiled

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

**Folder Tree**

[image]

**Gulp.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

mix.sass('app.scss')
   .script('app.js')
   .version( ['css/app.css','js/app.js']);

});
```

Why is script not building and doesn't create **js** folder in **public/build** and not even added in **`rev-manifest.json`**?
that's why when i call it to my **Html**, it throw's an error: "File js/app.js not defined in asset manifest".

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **scripts** (plural) method assumes all paths are relative to the `resources/assets/js` directory, and will place the resulting JavaScript in `public/js/all.js` by default. If you need to change the destination folder you can use the second parameter:

```
.scripts(['app.js'], 'public/build/js/app.js')
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i did this, but still it doesn't create the `js` file in `build` folder :(